# Cant open files in Visual studio Code by double click

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can´t open files in Visual Studio Code by doubleclicking on them in the regular Windows Explorer.

I can open files and folders by choosing "File"->"Open File" in the program itself, and i can drag and drop from the Explorer. But not via doubleclick.

I am sure that i have associated the files with the right program/exe-file

Does anyone have any clues?

Kind regards
Henrik

Comment: You have to associate the file with the application. Wrong site.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that the filetype is associated with the application

Comment: Then uninstall/reinstall. Still borked? Reinstall windows.

Comment: When you right-click on a file in the file explorer, go to properties and "Opens with:" does it say Visual Studio Code?  If not change it there.

Comment: Yes it does, and it works with Sublime Text, Notepad++ and all other software. I guess i will have to try and reinstall.